# Averaging values across rows and columns conditional on values in other columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to average values across some rows and columns conditional on values in other columns using pandas. The dataframe contains the following information:

- columns indicating accuracy (abbreviated 'acc')

  - 0 = no response
  - 1 = incorrect
  - 2 = correct
- columns indicating reaction times (abbreviated 'rt')

Here is an excerpt of the information in the dataframe:

```
a1_acc a1_rt a2_acc a2_rt a3_acc a3_rt b_acc b_rt
2      780   2      830   2      690   2     950
1      630   2      750   0      0     2     890
2      710   2      810   1      740   1     820
```

What I would like to do is to combine all 'a' (but not 'b') reaction times if they are from correct responses. That is, I would like a numpy array (or other suitable data structure) containing the following reaction times:

```
780, 830, 690, 750, 710, 810
```

Based on this information, I would then like to compute mean reaction times (after rejecting reaction times deviating more than 3 standard deviations from the mean).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

I think that's not the best shape for your DataFrame -- I think columns like "letter", "number", "acc", "rt" or something (giving them more meaningful names) would be easier to pivot.  Anyway, with your current arrangement:

```
>>> d
   a1_acc  a1_rt  a2_acc  a2_rt  a3_acc  a3_rt  b_acc  b_rt
0       2    780       2    830       2    690      2   950
1       1    630       2    750       0      0      2   890
2       2    710       2    810       1    740      1   820
```

First, we slice `.ix` to get the `_acc` columns and compare them to 2:

```
>>> d.ix[:,0:6:2] == 2
  a1_acc a2_acc a3_acc
0   True   True   True
1  False   True  False
2   True   True  False
```

Then we apply this to a slice of the `_rt` columns:

```
>>> d.ix[:, 1:6:2][d.ix[:,0:6:2] == 2]
   a1_rt  a2_rt  a3_rt
0    780    830    690
1    NaN    750    NaN
2    710    810    NaN
```

Flatten this:

```
>>> v = d.ix[:, 1:6:2][d.ix[:,0:6:2] == 2].unstack()
>>> v
a1_rt  0    780
       1    NaN
       2    710
a2_rt  0    830
       1    750
       2    810
a3_rt  0    690
       1    NaN
       2    NaN
```

And now we can take the mean and see the standard deviations (there might be a builtin function to do this, but I'm too lazy to look it up), automatically ignoring the `NaN` values where needed:

```
>>> v.mean()
761.66666666666663
>>> dev = ((v-v.mean())/v.std()).abs() < 3
>>> dev
a1_rt  0     True
       1    False
       2     True
a2_rt  0     True
       1     True
       2     True
a3_rt  0     True
       1    False
       2    False
```

All the values which we're using are within 3 standard deviations, so this cut isn't very interesting, but we can apply it anyhow:

```
>>> v[dev].mean()
761.66666666666663
```

Again, I'd look into reshaping your data at the start, so the `.ix` ugliness could have been something more like `d[(d["letter"] == a) & (d["acc"] == 2)]["rt"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful reply! The data in their current form are read in from a text file and I have to admit that I wouldn't be sure how to correctly reshape them at the start. To make things even more complicated, there is the additional requirement that 'a' reaction times should only be considered when 'b' is correct (so, 710 and 810 from the example above should actually not be included in the computation of mean).